# npm install not installing all the dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I tried installing all dependencies using `npm install`, but the dependencies were not being installed in the current project. It shows the below message.

[image: The result being shown after npm install]

Then I tried auditing using `npm audit`. That also shown "found vulnerabilities" as below screenshot.

[image: the result of npm audit]

But finally, when I tried to fix the vulnerabilities using `npm audit fix`, it could not find the vulnerabilities and shows "found 0 of 0 vulnerabilities" as below screenshot.

[image: the result of npm audit fix]

Help me installing all dependencies using `npm install`.

I have installed node v10.15.0 and npm v6.4.1 in a windows system.

Comment: Package dependency modules are stored in a  `node_modules` folder automatically created for you in the project folder. By "the dependencies were not being installed in the current project" in the post, do you mean that `npm install` did **not** create a `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @traktor53 Yes. Packages were not created in the `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The two warnings are being generated because:

1. There is no, or an empty string, property definition of "description" in the project's `package.json` file. It may not be mandatory, but uploading the project without a description makes it hard to search for.
2. There is no, or an empty string, property definition of "repository" in the `package.json` file. Normally this where you would put the url of the project in a repository like GitHub, but it's not mandatory.

Typically one enters these fields in response to install questions when first running `npm install` in the project folder, but you can always edit `package.json` to add or update them later.

Counting the spaces in `found   vulnerabilities found` and the `audit fix` output suggests there is a count of `0` in `found 0 vulnerabilities` that can't be seen. Try directing output to a file, e.g. by running `npm install >log.txt` in the project folder, to be certain. Basically the major problem seems to be terminal rendition of colored text.

Colored text is produced by inserting [ANSI escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) into NPM output strings and usually works in standard system terminal programs  - for example, Windows 10 `cmd` logs the message in white text with the `0` presented in green, both on a dark background, meaning it's completely readable.

Comment: The output of `npm install > log.txt` doesn't seem to be different.

Comment: Hi @traktor53, I had changed the colored text to the default white. After that also getting the same outputs of `npm install`, `npm audit` and `npm audit fix`.